# Simple transistor resistor amplifier circuit question

Tags: transistors, amplifier, resistors, voltage-divider

Can someone please help me solve this?  I have tried and got stuck.

In a point that can I apply Kirchhoff's voltage law around R2,R4 loop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0F4tf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You have to show what you have tried on this site otherwise it looks like we're doing your homework and we don't do that here (as that teaches you nothing). Hint: Ic is given, with \$\beta\$ that gives you Ib. Then determine Ie. What is the voltage across R4?

Comment: could you please tell me whether I can apply Kirchhoff's Voltage Low around R2 and R4 loop

Comment: @ShakthiSachintha You don't need anything complicated. You know IC so you can work out the collector voltage. You know VCE so you can then work out the emitter voltage. You know VBE so you can then work out the base voltage. You have all the voltage values. You also know the current in R1, so you can compute that value. You know the current in R2 is there same, less IB, so you can compute R2. And you know the emitter current is IC+IB, so you can work out R4. Just do the calcs.

Comment: *could you please tell me whether I can apply Kirchhoff's Voltage Low around R2 and R4 loop* It's a **Law** meaning it can always be applied in the situation where it applies. That's loops in circuits. Is this a circuit and does it have a loop? If you are uncertain about KVL and KCL then you're not really ready to tackle these kinds of circuits.

Comment: @jonk I ve solved the problem. Thanks for your support. Highly Appreciated.

Comment: @ShakthiSachintha You are welcome. And thanks for letting me know it helped!

Comment: I thought this was a trick question for the student. How can there be any current flow at all if VBE is only .3V? Unless it's germanium, highly doubtful.

Comment: The problem does state that \$I_C\$ so it seems that the transistor is not cut off. However, I agree that the problem is poorly defined.

Comment: These are didactical examples. Their only purpose is to allow the student to get acquainted with the analysis and design process, they are not supposed to be built in the real world.

Comment: I think I solved this puzzle with Ohm's Law. Am I right? R1=25.5K, R2=19.5K, R4=1.8K.

Comment: I didn't see the answers above.  Slightly off because I rounded off numbers and ignored the base current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwqxSR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When analyzing a transistor we need to use the following [relations](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html):

- $$\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_\text{C}\tag1$$
- Transistor gain \$\beta\$:
  $$\beta=\frac{\text{I}_\text{C}}{\text{I}_\text{B}}\tag2$$

Using KCL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{x}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_\text{T}+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{x}=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_\text{T}+\text{I}_1\\
\\
\beta=\frac{\text{I}_1}{\text{I}_\text{T}}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Using KVL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3=\alpha
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{R}_2,\text{R}_3\$ and \$\text{R}_4\$.

---

Using your values we get:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ix == 2*10^(-3) + I3, I3 == It + I4, Ix == I2 + I4, 
   I2 == It + 2*10^(-3), 100 == 2*10^(-3)/It, 
   2*10^(-3) == (9 - V1)/1200, I2 == (V3)/R2, I3 == (9 - V2)/R3, 
   I4 == (V2)/R4, V2 - V3 == 3/10, V1 - V3 == 3, I3 == 10*It}, {Ix, 
   It, I2, I3, I4, V1, V2, V3, R2, R3, R4}]]
```

Which gives:

```
{{Ix -> 11/5000, It -> 1/50000, I2 -> 101/50000, I3 -> 1/5000, 
  I4 -> 9/50000, V1 -> 33/5, V2 -> 39/10, V3 -> 18/5, 
  R2 -> 180000/101, R3 -> 25500, R4 -> 65000/3}}
```

And that is the same as:

```
{{Ix -> 0.0022, It -> 0.00002, I2 -> 0.00202, I3 -> 0.0002, 
  I4 -> 0.00018, V1 -> 6.6, V2 -> 3.9, V3 -> 3.6, R2 -> 1782.18, 
  R3 -> 25500., R4 -> 21666.7}}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer . this helped a lot.